# Rust compilation error: 'move occurs because `self.styles` has type `HashMap<&str, &str>`'

Tags: rust

I have been trying to write simple logger "class" that can display test message in colors. I am running into the compilation error. What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it ? (please note i'd like to fix this particular issue not to replace what i am doing with some coloring crate, etc... it's a learning exercise for me).

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.styles` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:21:30
   |
21 |         for (style, term) in self.styles {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.styles` has type `HashMap<&str, &str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Code...

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Logger <'a> {
    styles: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
}

impl Logger <'_> {
    fn new() -> Logger <'static> {
        let mut logger = Logger{styles: HashMap::new()};
        logger.styles.insert("</>", "\x1b[0m");
        logger.styles.insert("<WARN>", "\x1b[1m\x1b[93m");
        logger.styles.insert("<CRIT>", "\x1b[41m");
        logger.styles.insert("<INFO>", "\x1b[1m");
        logger
    }

    fn log(&self, message: &str) {
        let mut output = String::new();
        for (style, term) in self.styles {
            output = message.replace(style, term);
        }
        println!("{}", output)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let logger = Logger::new();

    logger.log("<INFO>Logger</> written in <CRIT>Rust</> language, <WARN>2021</>");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop has an implicit call to [`.into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.into_iter-2). From the docs (emphasis mine):

> Creates a consuming iterator, that is, one that moves each key-value pair out of the map in arbitrary order. **The map cannot be used after calling this.**

So the for loop is trying to move `self.styles` since it doesn't implement the `Copy` trait. Try borrowing instead:

```rust
for (&style, &term) in &self.styles {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Solution works perfectly, thank you very much !!! :)